# For Every duplicated value in Id Column how can i append a string 'duplicated' with that value

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have created a dataframe

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'Weather':[32,45,12,18,19,27,39,11,22,42],
            'Id':[1,2,3,4,5,1,6,7,8,2]})
df.head()
```

You can see Id on index 5th and 9th are duplicated. So, I want to append string --duplicated with Id on 5th and 9th index.

```
df.loc[df['Id'].duplicated()]
```

**Output**

```
   Weather  Id
5   27      1
9   42      2
```

**Expected output**

```
    Weather Id
5   27      1--duplicated
9   42      2--duplicated
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want an aggregated DataFrame with modification of your previous output using [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)?

```
(df.loc[df['Id'].duplicated()]
   .assign(Id=lambda d: d['Id'].astype(str).add('--duplicated'))
)
```

output:

```
   Weather             Id
5       27  1--duplicated
9       42  2--duplicated
```

Or, in place modification of the original DataFrame with [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)?

```
m = df['Id'].duplicated()
df.loc[m, 'Id'] = df.loc[m, 'Id'].astype(str)+'--duplicated'
```

Output:

```
   Weather             Id
0       32              1
1       45              2
2       12              3
3       18              4
4       19              5
5       27  1--duplicated
6       39              6
7       11              7
8       22              8
9       42  2--duplicated
```

Answer (score 1):

If need add suffix to filtered rows use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) by mask :

```
m = df['Id'].duplicated()
df.loc[m,'Id' ] = df.loc[m,'Id' ].astype(str).add('--duplicated')
print (df)
   Weather             Id
0       32              1
1       45              2
2       12              3
3       18              4
4       19              5
5       27  1--duplicated
6       39              6
7       11              7
8       22              8
9       42  2--duplicated
```

Or use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and then add suffix:

```
df1 = df[df['Id'].duplicated()].copy()
df1['Id'] = df1['Id'].astype(str) + '--duplicated'
print (df1)
   Weather             Id
5       27  1--duplicated
9       42  2--duplicated
```